# Taking a screenshot of aframe scene and save it to server without popups

Tags: javascript, screenshot, aframe

The code:

```
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script>
  AFRAME.registerComponent("foo", {
    init: function() {
      document.querySelector('a-scene').components.screenshot.capture('perspective')
    }
  })

</script>
<a-scene screenshot="width: 640; height: 320" foo>
  <a-entity id="box" geometry="primitive: box; width: 1; depth: 1; height: 1" position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" material="color: #4CC3D9"></a-entity>
  <a-entity id="sphere" geometry="primitive: sphere; radius: 1.25" material="color: #EF2D5E" position="0 1.25 -5"></a-entity>
  <a-entity id="cylinder" geometry="primitive: cylinder; radius: 0.5; height: 1.5" position="1 0.75 -3" material="color: #FFC65D"></a-entity>
  <a-entity id="plane" position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" geometry="primitive: plane; width: 4; height: 4" material="color: #7BC8A4"></a-entity>
  <a-entity id="sky" geometry="primitive: sphere; radius: 100" material="color: #ECECEC; shader: flat; side: back"></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

This code is like ctrl + alt + s click, and opens a new window.
I need to save a screenshot of the scene without clicks or popups.

Other problem is the screenshot goes completely white or like this:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0St2.png)

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) library its easy to use and works.
Also, Google used it to implement the Thanos click effect on the google page.
[Here](https://www.google.com/search?q=thanos), visit the link and click on the gauntlet.

Comment: I already tried html2canvas before but the image goes completely white